# Return factors of a monomial in Maple.

Tags: math-software, maple

Let $$ m = Y_{{1,0}}{Y_{{1,2}}}^{2}Y_{{2,5}}Y_{{1,8}}. $$ Using the function op in Maple, we have $op(m) = Y[1, 0], Y[1, 2]^2, Y[2, 5], Y[1, 8]$. But $op(Y[1,0])=1,0$ and $op(Y[1,0]^2)=Y[1,0],2$. Are there some functions in Maple such that the value of $$ Y_{{1,0}}{Y_{{1,2}}}^{2}Y_{{2,5}}Y_{{1,8}} $$ is $Y[1, 0], Y[1, 2]^2, Y[2, 5], Y[1, 8]$ and the value of $Y[1,0]^n$ is $Y[1,0]^n$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$ that you need is

```
f:= P-> `if`(P::`*`, op(P), P);
```

Note carefully the two pairs of backquotes.

Answer (score 0):

Well 
$$ [op(m)][2] = {Y_{{1,2}}}^{2}. $$

Comment: thank you very much. But I need some function $f$ such that $f(Y[1,2]^2)=Y[1,2]^2$.

Comment: Let f:=x->x:  then $f(Y[1,2]^2)=Y[1,2]^2.$